# Binding a ContentPresenter to a nested ViewModel doesn't work as expected

Tags: winrt-xaml, mvvmcross

Target: Windows Store
Framework: MvvmCross

I have MyViewModel containing OtherViewModel as a property.

```
public class OtherViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    private OtherViewModel _theOther;

    public OtherViewModel TheOther
    {
        get { return _theOther; }
        set
        {
            _theOther = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => TheOther);
        }
    }        
}
```

When I use the following View (XAML, simplified)), the Content of the ContentPresenter will always be null (using WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging.DC.ShowVisualTree() to investigate)

```
<views:MvxStorePage>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TheOther.Name}"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TheOther}" ContentTemplate="{...}"/>
    </Grid>
</views:MvxStorePage>
```

However, when I define the view the following way (binding the Content to the TextBlock DataContext) it works.

```
<views:MvxStorePage>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="tb" DataContext="{Binding TheOther}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=tb}" ContentTemplate="{...}"/>
        </Grid>
    </views:MvxStorePage>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Try using a `ContentControl` instead of a `ContentPresenter`.

Answer (score 3):

ContentPresenter is usually used in a ControlTemplate.

Use a ContentControl instead.

Comment: Got it working with using the ContentControl instead of ContentPresenter, although I find this illogical.
In WPF I would use a ContentPresenter for this, and not a ContentControl.
Also, why is it the DataBinding on the ContentPresenter does not work when bound 'directly', but does work using an 'intermediate' (the TextBlock)

Answer (score 0):

> You typically use the ContentPresenter in the ControlTemplate of a
>   ContentControl to specify where the content is to be added. Every
>   ContentControl type has a ContentPresenter in its default
>   ControlTemplate.

See this  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter) for more information